# Find location of a control in wpf using PointToScreen

Tags: c#, wpf, point

I'm trying to find my relative coordinate for a usercontrol inside my mainwindow. I tried using the "Control.PointToScreen()" method but with no luck. Everytime I do this i get an exception that says:

**System.InvalidOperationException: This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource**

I think this has something to do with me calling pointToScreen before the visuals have rendered properly, since i'm already calling the method in my Mains Constructor.

Anyways, I would like to hear if anyone of you had a hint/Solution/Idea how I could perhaps work around this.

**Just to clearify what i'm trying to do, my control contains a photocontrol which i need the exact location off inside my maincontrol, since i want to use these coordinates to create a duplicate of the control on top of it**

Experimenting with PointToScreen.

Comment: Why use PointToScreen when you want it relative to your main window? You may use [`TranslatePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) instead. And you may need to call this after the window has been loaded. There is a [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event for that purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your code register for the Loaded event of the UserControl.
That should fix the bug that the visuals have not been rendered yet when you try to get the position.

```cs
YourControl.Loaded += ControlLoaded;

public void ControlLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Console.WriteLine(YourControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
}
```

### Edit

Since you want the position of your control relative to your window, better try that one .

```cs
YourControl.TransformToAncestor(YourWindow).Transform(new Point(0,0))
```

Comment: So ye this solved half my problem. I think it's because the element im looking for is not within my mainwindow, but further in, inside a usercontrol. So Your example worked for all controls lying inside my mainwindow, but i guess i have to wait for the loaded event to kick in under my child controls and then return the point back to my mainwindow. Thanks for your help. I can work the rest my self from that ;)

Comment: Well sadly it didn't help with the underlying problem. It keeps giving me the same exception.

I'm not sure exactly why i'm getting the errors, cause I feel I do the same as your first example :/

Comment: Like :

Console.WriteLine(YourControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0)); THIS WORKS

Console.WriteLine(YourControl.GetChildControl().PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));

THIS Doesn't

Comment: So you get the "Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource" error again? You registered for the Loaded event of the nested controls?

Comment: i would try to register for the Loaded event of the nested control. Is this event fired you could be sure it got rendered.

Comment: I already did. So the NestedControls Loaded event fires before the mainwindows loaded event, but gives me the same error. So this is also a dead end. I tried locating all my stackpanels, borders, grids and so on without luck.. 

Could it perhaps be that which is the problem? That containers can't be used with pointToScreen?

Comment: PointToScreen() also works for Containers. Maybe you should try the ContentRendered event of the MainWindow, that should fire after all controls are rendered. Does that one work?

Comment: Since ContentRendered event doesn't exist I found something else that actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since Contend rendered didn't work I found a solution for my problem.

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ItemsControl ItemsControl = UCEnvironmentControl.GetItemsControlPhotos();
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => Control.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
}
```

This way, it fires in the LoadedEvent, but waits for the content to be rendered, and then finally it gives you your coordinate back and sets your control

Comment: Nice that you found a way to solve your problem :) The ContentRendered method was meant to be used with the window. Window.ContentRendered should be raised when all content inside the window is loaded.

Comment: I see, Apparently a usercontrol doesn't have this method, and my application is part of a larger system, so it's not window based :) But thank you anyway for your help, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Max Mazur is working for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Point locationOfYourControl;

        public MainWindow()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
        }

        private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            locationOfYourControl = YourControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
```