# WPF ContentRendered on screen event to find coordinates of control

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, dispatcher

This is a follow up question to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802945/find-location-of-a-control-in-wpf-using-pointtoscreen).

I found up how to find a controls coordinates upon when the control was loaded, however now after it's been loaded, and i update the layout coordinates, I have a hard time finding out which type of event / DispatcherPriority i need to use.

I've been through all dispatcher priorities and nothing worked out there.

My code so far looks like this:

```
    if (UCEnvironmentControl.GetItemsControlPhotos() != null)
      {
        ItemsControl ItemsControlEnvironment = UCEnvironmentControl.GetItemsControlPhotos();
        if (this.IsLoaded) {
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => SetFormCopyPhotos(ItemsControlEnvironment)));
        } else {
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => SetFormCopyPhotos(ItemsControlEnvironment)));
        }
      }
```

So as you can see i call the BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded....) when my control is loaded, and this works fine, the other one is apparrently called to early, or somewhere in between rendering since the X Coordinate is wrong (X is dynamic, Y is Static). I collapse some items just before "if(this.isLoaded)" which causes the control im looking for to move.

I hope this is enough information I can't really provide anymore right now, so any suggestions will be greetet with open arms!

Comment: maybe won´t solve your problem, but i noticed that the second if(this.IsLoaded) statement should be always true, so the else branch is not reachable here? or am i missing something ?

Comment: That was a typo..Going to correct that asap.

Comment: i´m not sure if i understand your question correctly. Do you wan´t to get the event when your control has moved ? Did you try the "LayoutUpdated" event?

Comment: The problem about LayoutUpdated is that it is constantly triggering. So it's nearly impossible to keep track of

edit: and it didn't really help me :/

Comment: Does your usercontrol change its size when its being moved? Than maybe the SizeChanged event will work for you? That shouldn´t be fired that often. :)

Comment: SizeChanged didn't work either.. I've been through all relevant events now, I just gotta figure out a work around

Comment: But am i getting you right that you want to get the coordinates of your control again when some other control gets collapsed? sorry to ask again but i think i don´t get your question right

Comment: Yes something like that.